# ¿Porqué no reconoce el string descargado de una pagina mediante WebClient().DownloadString("https://....") el switch en C sharp?

Tags: c#, switch

bueno tengo el siguiente problema, que me persigue hace tiempo, la idea es que mediante una pagina web se logre descargar el "Country Code" y que esta información que queda en forma de string se pueda usar con un switch para asociarlo a la bandera correspondiente, a todo esto las banderas están en una sola imagen, el programa busca una sección de la imagen donde sale la bandera correspondiente...

public partial class Form1 : Form

```
{
    public static string externalCountry = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://ipinfo.io/country").ToLower();
    
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        flagCountry(0, 0);

    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label3.Text = externalCountry;
        textBoxFlag.Text = externalCountry;
    }

    private void flagCountry( int cropx, int cropy)
    {

        int cropX = cropx;
        int cropY = cropy;
        int cropWidth = 32;
        int cropHeight = 32;
        var img = Properties.Resources.flags32;            
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight);
        var cloned = new Bitmap(img).Clone(rect, img.PixelFormat);
        pFlag.Image = cloned;
      

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        switch (externalCountry)

        {
            case "AR": flagCountry(32, 0); labelFlag.Text = "Argentina"; break;
            case "CL": flagCountry(64, 0); labelFlag.Text = "Chile"; break;
            case "AU": flagCountry(96, 0); labelFlag.Text = "Australia"; break;
            case "CA": flagCountry(128, 0); labelFlag.Text = "Canada"; break;
            case "JP": flagCountry(160, 0); labelFlag.Text = "Japon"; break;
            case "FI": flagCountry(192, 0); labelFlag.Text = "Finland"; break;
            
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No lo reconoce por dos cosas:

1. El código se está convirtiendo a minúsculas pero los casos están en mayúscula.
2. Al final del código hay un salto de línea `\n` que debe removerse.

---

```
public class Program
{
    public static string externalCountry = new WebClient()
    .DownloadString("https://ipinfo.io/country")
    .Replace("\n","");

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
       switch(externalCountry){
           case  "SV":
           Console.WriteLine("Hola SV");
           break;
       }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente!!! era el salto de linea, wow!! muchas gracias por responder a mi pregunta